# Angular with MSAL using AD FS (on-prem AD, not Azure AD) calling secure .NET Core Web API

Tags: angular, asp.net-core-webapi, azure-ad-msal, adfs

I have an Angular 9 front end with .NET Core 3.1 Web API on the back end.

On the front end, users are authenticated with MSAL 2.x against *on-prem* AD using AD FS. There is *no* Azure or cloud component to the solution.

Login, logout, and guarded routes are all working, but API calls to [Authorize] endpoints aren't. I'm 99% certain it has something to do with the MSAL protected resource map and the relying party trust in AD FS.

The POST for the oauth token consistently fails with a 400 and "No resource with given identifier found", which MSAL responds to bey refreshing the browser page and throwing the error `invalid_resource: MSIS9602: The received 'resource' parameter is invalid. The authorization server can not find a registered resource with the specified identifier.`

Here's the 400 when the API call is attempted:
[image]

[image]

Then the page refreshes in the browser and MSAL throws the error:
[image]

This my protected resource map configuration in `app.module`:
[image]

Which matches with the relying party trust identifier in AD FS:
[image]

I am at my wits end trying to resolve this, so much gratitude to anyone that has an answer to this problem. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What ADFS version? I believe MSAL only support ADFS 2019. Maybe this blog will be a help https://blogs.aaddevsup.xyz/2021/12/msal-js-spa-client-performing-authorization-code-grant-flow-to-adfs-2019/

Comment: ADFS 2019 of course. I'm aware that 2016 is not supported. And that's the very blog post I followed to the letter, where in fact, I'm able to get a working version just like the post explains. But that's using plain JS on the front end (not Angular), and .NET Framework on the back end (not .NET Core). This problem occurs using MSAL with Angular specifically.